# Why is my Linux prio based tc not improving network latency?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ip, qos

I am building a real-time embedded linux application that has a variety of network traffic.  Of the set of traffic, two connections are time critical.  One is the input data and the other for output data.  My application needs this traffic to have priority over the other, non-time-critical traffic.

I care about two things:

1. Minimize the number of dropped packets due to overload on these two connections.
2. Minimize the latency through the device (input to output) on these two connnections.

I've come (somewhat!) up to speed on Linux traffic control, and understand that it primarly applies to egress traffic, as the remote device is responsible for the priority of data it sends to me.  I have setup my application as a real time process and have worked through the issues related to what priority to run it at.

I now embark on setting up tc.  For my test case, here is what I use:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio bands 3 priomap 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: pfifo
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: pfifo
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3 handle 30: pfifo
```

Basically I am saying:  Send all priority 7 traffic over band 0, and *all* other traffic over band 2.  Once I have this simple test working I will do a better job handling other traffic.

First let's verify my expectations:
What I expect is that any traffic having priority 7 should always go out before traffic having *any* other priority.  This should make the latency on such traffic be relatively unaffected by other traffic on the box, no?  My mtu is set to 1500, and I am getting about 10 MB/sec through the interface.  The maximum additional latency on band 0 caused by band 2 traffic is one packet (<=1500 bytes), or 150 us (1500 bytes / 10 MBytes/sec = 150 us).

Here is my test setup:

Two Linux Boxes.  Box 1 running a TCP server that echos input data.  Box 2 connects to box one, sends packets over TCP and measures the latency (time sent to time received).

I use the same tc setup for box Linux boxes.

In the applications (both server and client), I set the SO_PRIORITY on the socket as follows:

```
int so_priority = 7;
setsockopt(m_socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, &so_priority, sizeof(so_priority));
```

I use tc to verify that my traffic goes over band 0, and all other traffic over band 2:

```
tc -s qdisc ls dev eth0
```

Here's the rub: When there is no other traffic, I see latencies in the 500 us range.  When I have other traffic (for example, a scp job copying a 100 MB file), the latencies jump up to 10+ ms.  What is really strange is that NONE of the tc work I did has any affect.  In fact, if I swap the bands (so all my traffic goes over the lower priority band 2, and other traffic over band 1), I don't see any difference in latency.

What I was expecting is that when there is other traffic on the network, I would see an increase in latency of about 150 us, not 10 ms!  By the way, I have verified that loading the box with other (non-real time priority) processes does not affect latency, nor does traffic on other interfaces.

One other item of note is that if I drop the mtu to 500 bytes, the latency decreases to about 5 ms.  Still, this is an order of magnitude worse than the unloaded case.  Also--why does changing the mtu affect it so much, but using tc to setup priority queuing has no effect???

Why is tc not helping me?  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: As far as I know, prio based tc improves *bandwidth*, not latency.

Comment: Mike - That doesn't match the documentation.  If you "man prio", it says "Very useful for lowering latency when there is no need for slowing down traffic."  That is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say anything about the rest of your network, but I'm guessing you're hitting a queue at an upstream router, which usually have long queues to optimize for throughput.  The best way to fix it is to feed your priority queue into a shaper with a bandwidth just under your upstream bandwidth.  That way your bulk-priority packets will queue up inside your box instead of at an external router, allowing your high-priority packets to jump to the front of the queue as you expect.

Comment: Sounds right on. So, I removed all switches between the two boxes (the ethernet port has auto-crossover support), and reran the test--same results.  Could this be related to using TCP?

Comment: Nope.  Reran with UDP and am seeing the same problem.  Aargh!!

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe try this suggestion from the bugs section on the man page:  Large amounts of traffic in the lower bands can cause starvation of higher bands. Can be prevented by attaching a shaper (for example, tc-tbf(8) to these bands to make sure they cannot dominate the link.

Comment: Just had another thought.  If your bulk traffic is going to the same host as your interactive traffic, it might be queueing up on ingress.  I don't know much about the ingress side, but maybe try setting up the same priority queue on that side?

Comment: That is a nice (not) comment in the bugs section. Seems like a glaring bug. I set up a token bucket to limit traffic flow. This definitely helped, (latencies came down to ~8 ms max), but definitely did not solve the problem.

Comment: From my understanding, traffic control is on egress only.  Ingress can be used for policing, but otherwise, all it can do is drop packets.  I have the traffic control settings setup on both boxes.  Thus, the ingress side of one box is effectively controlled by the egress of the other box.

Answer (score 0):

The prio facility will simply send the highest priority packet available at the time when it is sending packets (typically as soon as the previous packet has been sent unless there are no packets waiting to go out).

Your test relies on the packets having been placed in the queue by the appropriate program's processes on each machine, and received packets having been retrieved from port on each machine.

Any scheduling delays which affect the time that a process gets on either machine might affect the process's ability to place a message on the queue or to retrieve and process a message form the queue. It sounds like you have loaded at least one of the machines to test for this but my experience is that machine loading will definitely affect measured latency like this (in the order of milliseconds not microseconds) so it might be worth repeating this with both machines loaded with high priority tasks.

The other thing to check is the timestamp you are using to measure the latency - is it the time the echoed message is actually received at the client machine or the time your program processes it. If the latter then you are measuring not just the network latency, but also the time between the message being received and your program getting a slice of the processor and getting to the point where you check the time - see http://wiki.wireshark.org/Timestamps.

As an aside, I don't think you will be able to to get guaranteed micro second level responsiveness without a real time OS like mechanism. On the other hand if your application is VoIP like then you will usually be OK up to about 200 millisecond latency.

Comment: We have already addressed process scheduling (significantly).  The Linux kernel now has enough real time support to ensure the process gets the CPU as soon as a packet is ready.

Comment: As for the timestamp, I am using tcpdump to record the time.  So, this is at the OS level.  However, as I mentioned, we have set up real time priorities such.  I can heavily load the box (CPU, disk, and traffic on other interfaces) with no affect on latency.  It is only when I add traffic to the SAME interface that I see latency impacted.

Comment: It would be worth finding out exactly what make and version your physical IP port is (the one that you are doing the latency testing on if you have multiple physical IP interfaces). When you have many processes running on the same CPU and using the same port, how the port works is important. If it can only do one thing at a time, it may have to wait until it fully sends a large packet before it passes a received packet to the OS (where you are time stamping it). You can experiment by changing the packet size of your traffic you are using to load up the interface and see if this has an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to capture the packets and check if the TOS value of the IP header have been changed ?

you need linux 2.6.39 or higher in order to use the SO_PRIORITY.

you should change the IP_TOS instead.

you should set:

```
int iptos_precedence = 0xc0;
if (setsockopt(sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, &iptos_precedence, sizeof(iptos_precedence)) < 0) {
           //print errno (or something like that)
}
```